# Contents chapter change color using fncychap

Tags: chapters, fncychap

How can I change the contents chapter to get the same color as my other chapters?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{geometry,tikz,caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,tikzmark}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}

\ChNameVar{\Large\fontfamily{put}\selectfont\color{blue!75!black}}

\geometry{innermargin=60pt,top=125pt,
    textwidth=345pt,textheight=598pt,
    marginparwidth=135pt,marginparsep=30pt,
    heightrounded}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Indholdsfortegnelse}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[figurename=Figur]{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,tikzmark,patterns}

\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\newcommand{\mymarginpar}[1]{\marginpar{\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}#1}}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Kapitel}

\title{Differentialregning}
\author{Jakob Blom Kruse}
\date{2021}


\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    % Fjerne header på inholdsfortegnelsen
    \clearpage
    \ifodd\value{page}\else
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \fi
    \chapter{Integralregning}
    \section{Introduktion}
    Her er den For at kunne kaste os ud i det nye emne omkring så kan vi se hpå hvad der skler i denne del mnår vi skriver en masse ogsv såmvsvm sknvpk psnp n  differentialreg\\   
    \newpage
    asæmsdv\\
    ælmdvzxbmxbdfbxxfblkn dkb dlb dlb dkl dk dm dmlb dmfx xmb d xbmd. kdsæ dml dsmxf vkxf vkx ks ksdf .vmds. bvksf sf vsmf.vsk f.xv xm. vsmx. vxkf vsm.fxv mxfv mx,v xmv m,xf v\\sdcv
    

    asæmsdv\\
    ælmdvzxbmxbdfbxxfblkn dkb dlb dlb dkl dk dm dmlb dmfx xmb d xbmd. kdsæ dml dsmxf vkxf vkx ks ksdf .vmds. bvksf sf vsmf.vsk f.xv xm. vsmx. vxkf vsm.fxv mxfv mx,v xmv m,xf v
    asæmsdv\\
    ælmdvzxbmxbdfbxxfblkn dkb dlb dlb dkl dk dm dmlb dmfx xmb d xbmd. kdsæ dml dsmxf vkxf vkx ks ksdf .vmds. bvksf sf vsmf.vsk f.xv xm. vsmx. vxkf vsm.fxv mxfv mx,v xmv m,xf v\\sdcv
    asæmsdv\\
    ælmdvzxbmxbdfbxxfblkn dkb dlb dlb dkl dk dm dmlb dmfx xmb d xbmd. kdsæ dml dsmxf vkxf vkx ks ksdf .vmds. bvksf sf vsmf.vsk f.xv xm. vsmx. vxkf vsm.fxv mxfv mx,v xmv m,xf v\\sdcvasæmsdv\\
    ælmdvzxbmxbdfbxxfblkn dkb dlb dlb dkl dk dm dmlb dmfx xmb d xbmd. kdsæ dml dsmxf vkxf vkx ks ksdf .vmds. bvksf sf vsmf.vsk f.xv xm. vsmx. vxkf vsm.fxv mxfv mx,v xmv m,xf v\\sdcv
    asæmsdv\\
    ælmdvzxbmxbdfbxxfblkn dkb dlb dlb dkl dk dm dmlb dmfx xmb d xbmd. kdsæ dml dsmxf vkxf vkx ks ksdf .vmds. bvksf sf vsmf.vsk f.xv xm. vsmx. vxkf vsm.fxv mxfv mx,v xmv m,xf v\\sdcv

    adsfdgfhadsfdg
    asdfgh\\
    \newpage
    
    aslrkgns \\
    skejfnsø ksfn
    
    \chapter{Differentialregning}
    \section{Sektion 2}
    Her er den For at kunne kaste os ud i det nye emne omkring så slæknv ks vlks væks vlks væskv kslv sv lksv lskv. smv .sm vksæ vms. vms vsm,,v sm,d vsm,dv s,m vs,md vs,mv
    \marginpar{\begin{footnotesize}
            En højre margisdfv kæ svxk sf sdfb dsbf dsfb dsbsdfb  sdfb dsfb  dsb dfb db dfb dbf dfb db n
        \end{footnotesize}
    }
    kan vi se hpå hvad der skler i denne del mnår vi skriver en masse ogsv såmvsvm sknvpk psnp n  differentialreg\\
    dgbc\\
    aæbcj\\
 
    
    sdf\\asb\\asfg\\
    sægsækg sækgs slrgs gs ger er den For at kunne kaste os ud i det nye emne omkring så kan vi se hpå hvad der skler i denne del 

    
    
    \subsection{Prøve på en undersektion}
    
    aeøfm
    
    \section{Sektion 3}
    \newpage    
    \section{Afslutning}
    Her er den For at kunne kaste os ud i det nye emne omkring så kan vi se hpå hvad der skler i denne del mnår vi skriver en masse ogsv såmvsvm sknvpk psnp n  differentialreg\\   

\end{document}
```

Now I get this

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't get `Glenn` to produce a toc at all (it reports many errors), but with a different style I added the command `\ChTitleVar{\Large\fontfamily{put}\selectfont\color{blue!75!black}}` and that seemed to fix things.

Comment: On a side note: You are loading the `caption` package twice and loading packages several times is usualy not a good idea. Also, `xcolor` is already implicitely loaded by `tikz`. 
I also saw you redefined things like `chaptername`, `figurename` etc. to (I guess) danish, and you could use the `babel` package to that for you.

Comment: @MarkusG. Thank you very much for helping me clean up my code. I learning a lot here in the beginning of my latex-adventure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you can select the color  of rulers and text style using `\stylecolor`.

I fixed an internal package command to have the same color for all rules used in chapters and table of contents.

[image: A]

Also rearranged the preamble and added `\frontmatter` and `\mainmattter` to get the proper page numbering. (see in the page of the TOC above and chapter pages)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}

\newcommand{\stylecolor}{\color{blue!75!black}} % choose the color  added <<<<

\ChNameVar{\stylecolor\Large\fontfamily{put}\selectfont}

\makeatletter % added <<<
\def\mghrulefill#1{\stylecolor\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\@height #1\hfill\kern\z@}
\makeatother

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{innermargin=60pt,top=125pt,
    textwidth=345pt,textheight=598pt,
    marginparwidth=135pt,marginparsep=30pt,
    heightrounded}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Indholdsfortegnelse}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[figurename=Figur]{caption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,tikzmark}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,tikzmark,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\newcommand{\mymarginpar}[1]{\marginpar{\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}#1}}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Kapitel}

\title{Differentialregning}
\author{Jakob Blom Kruse}
\date{2021}


\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
        % Fjerne header på inholdsfortegnelsen
    \clearpage
    \ifodd\value{page}\else
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \fi
    
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents    
    
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{Integralregning}
    \section{Introduktion}
    Her er den For at kunne kaste os ud i det nye emne omkring så kan vi se hpå hvad der skler i denne del mnår vi skriver en masse ogsv såmvsvm sknvpk psnp n  differentialreg\\   
    \newpage
    asæmsdv\\
    ælmdvzxbmxbdfbxxfblkn dkb dlb dlb dkl dk dm dmlb dmfx xmb d xbmd. kdsæ dml dsmxf vkxf vkx ks ksdf .vmds. bvksf sf vsmf.vsk f.xv xm. vsmx. vxkf vsm.fxv mxfv mx,v xmv m,xf v\\sdcv
    
    
    asæmsdv\\
    ælmdvzxbmxbdfbxxfblkn dkb dlb dlb dkl dk dm dmlb dmfx xmb d xbmd. kdsæ dml dsmxf vkxf vkx ks ksdf .vmds. bvksf sf vsmf.vsk f.xv xm. vsmx. vxkf vsm.fxv mxfv mx,v xmv m,xf v
    asæmsdv\\
    ælmdvzxbmxbdfbxxfblkn dkb dlb dlb dkl dk dm dmlb dmfx xmb d xbmd. kdsæ dml dsmxf vkxf vkx ks ksdf .vmds. bvksf sf vsmf.vsk f.xv xm. vsmx. vxkf vsm.fxv mxfv mx,v xmv m,xf v\\sdcv
    asæmsdv\\
    ælmdvzxbmxbdfbxxfblkn dkb dlb dlb dkl dk dm dmlb dmfx xmb d xbmd. kdsæ dml dsmxf vkxf vkx ks ksdf .vmds. bvksf sf vsmf.vsk f.xv xm. vsmx. vxkf vsm.fxv mxfv mx,v xmv m,xf v\\sdcvasæmsdv\\
    ælmdvzxbmxbdfbxxfblkn dkb dlb dlb dkl dk dm dmlb dmfx xmb d xbmd. kdsæ dml dsmxf vkxf vkx ks ksdf .vmds. bvksf sf vsmf.vsk f.xv xm. vsmx. vxkf vsm.fxv mxfv mx,v xmv m,xf v\\sdcv
    asæmsdv\\
    ælmdvzxbmxbdfbxxfblkn dkb dlb dlb dkl dk dm dmlb dmfx xmb d xbmd. kdsæ dml dsmxf vkxf vkx ks ksdf .vmds. bvksf sf vsmf.vsk f.xv xm. vsmx. vxkf vsm.fxv mxfv mx,v xmv m,xf v\\sdcv
    
    adsfdgfhadsfdg
    asdfgh\\
    \newpage
    
    aslrkgns \\
    skejfnsø ksfn
    
    \chapter{Differentialregning}
    \section{Sektion 2}
    Her er den For at kunne kaste os ud i det nye emne omkring så slæknv ks vlks væks vlks væskv kslv sv lksv lskv. smv .sm vksæ vms. vms vsm,,v sm,d vsm,dv s,m vs,md vs,mv
    \marginpar{\begin{footnotesize}
            En højre margisdfv kæ svxk sf sdfb dsbf dsfb dsbsdfb  sdfb dsfb  dsb dfb db dfb dbf dfb db n
        \end{footnotesize}
    }
    kan vi se hpå hvad der skler i denne del mnår vi skriver en masse ogsv såmvsvm sknvpk psnp n  differentialreg\\
    dgbc\\
    aæbcj\\
    
    
    sdf\\asb\\asfg\\
    sægsækg sækgs slrgs gs ger er den For at kunne kaste os ud i det nye emne omkring så kan vi se hpå hvad der skler i denne del 
    
    
    
    \subsection{Prøve på en undersektion}
    
    aeøfm
    
    \section{Sektion 3}
    \newpage    
    \section{Afslutning}
    Her er den For at kunne kaste os ud i det nye emne omkring så kan vi se hpå hvad der skler i denne del mnår vi skriver en masse ogsv såmvsvm sknvpk psnp n  differentialreg\\   
    
\end{document}
```